# script updates child table then stops for all other updates

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in a database:

- `Employee_info`(stores all employee information ) and
- `Job_Info`(store all job title , job description).

The code inserts the data with no problems but when updating this error is printed on the browser:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (Employee_database.job_info, CONSTRAINT job_info_ibfk_4 FOREIGN KEY
>   (Employee_Id) REFERENCES Employee_info (Employee_Id) ON UPDATE
>   CASCADE)

I am unable to get the value of `Employee_Id` for the child table to be updated or what could be the problem?

Here is the code

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `Employee_info` WHERE `Name_Of_Employee` = '$Name'";
   $sqlsearch = mysql_query($query);
       $resultcount = mysql_numrows($sqlsearch);
         if ($resultcount > 0) 
            {
                 $row=mysql_fetch_assoc ($sqlsearch);
                 $Employee_Id= $row['Employee_Id'];
                mysql_query("UPDATE  `employee_info` SET `Name_Of_Employee` = '$Name',

                                     `Physical_Address` = '$P_Address',

                                     `Phone_Number` = '$Phone',

                                     `Email_Address` = '$E_Address'
               WHERE `Name_Of_Employee` = '$Name'"
            )
            or die(mysql_error());
            }
            else {
                $sql="INSERT INTO employee_info
                     (
                         Name_Of_Employee,
                         Physical_Address,
                         Phone_Number,
                         Email_Address
                     )
                 VALUES (
                    '$Name',
                    '$P_Address',
                    '$Phone',
                    '$E_Address'
                        )";
                      if(!mysql_query($sql))
                         {    
                         die('cannot store in employee_info'.mysql_error());
                         }
                     }

       $Employee_Id=mysql_insert_id();
         $qry = "SELECT * FROM `Job_info` WHERE `Job_Title` = '$Job_Title'";
           $sqlsearch = mysql_query($query);
             $resultcount = mysql_numrows($sqlsearch);
               if ($resultcount > 0) {
                                       "UPDATE `Job_info` SET `Employee_Id` = '$Employee_Id' ,
                                               `Job_Title` = '$Job_Title',
                                               `Job_Description` = '$Job_Description'

                                        WHERE `Employee_Id` = '$Employee_Id'")
                                        or die(mysql_error());
                                     }
               else 
                    {
                      $sql="INSERT INTO ad_info (
                                                  Employee_Id,
                                                  Job_Title,
                                                  Job_Description
                                                )
                                         VALUES (
                                                 '$Employee_Id',
                                                 '$Job_Title',
                                                 '$Job_Description'
                                                )";
                       if(!mysql_query($sql))
                       {
                                                 die('cannot store in job info'.mysql_error());}




                                                 }
```

here is the databse design

```
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Employee_Id      | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Name_Of_Employee | varchar(20) | NO   |     |         |                |
| Physical_Address | varchar(25) | NO   |     |         |                |
| Phone_Number     | int(14)     | NO   |     |         |                |
| Email_address    | varchar(25) | NO   |     |         |                |                             |
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| jOB_Id           | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Employee_Id      | int(11)     | NO   |     |         |                |
| Job_Title        | varchar(25) | NO   |     |         |                |
| Job_Description  | text(100)   | NO   |     |         |                |
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when updating your $employee_id is empty. See they you are not setting it.

Your code should be:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Employee_info` WHERE `Name_Of_Employee` = '$Name'";
$sqlsearch = mysql_query($query);
$resultcount = mysql_numrows($sqlsearch);
if ($resultcount > 0) 
{
   $row=mysql_fetch_assoc ($sqlsearch);
   $Employee_Id= $row['Employee_Id'];
            mysql_query("UPDATE  `employee_info` SET `Name_Of_Employee` = '$Name',

                                 `Physical_Address` = '$P_Address',
                                 `Phone_Number` = '$Phone',
                                 `Email_Address` = '$E_Address'
           WHERE `Name_Of_Employee` = '$Name'"
        )
        or die(mysql_error());
        }
        else {
            $sql="INSERT INTO employee_info
                 (
                     Name_Of_Employee,
                     Physical_Address,
                     Phone_Number,
                     Email_Address
                 )
             VALUES (
                '$Name',
                '$P_Address',
                '$Phone',
                '$E_Address'
                    )";
          if(!mysql_query($sql))
          {    
                     die('cannot store in employee_info'.mysql_error());
          }
          $Employee_Id=mysql_insert_id();
   }


     $qry = "SELECT * FROM `Job_info` WHERE `Job_Title` = '$Job_Title'";
       $sqlsearch = mysql_query($query);
         $resultcount = mysql_numrows($sqlsearch);
           if ($resultcount > 0) {
                                   "UPDATE `Job_info` SET `Employee_Id` = '$Employee_Id' ,
                                           `Job_Title` = '$Job_Title',
                                           `Job_Description` = '$Job_Description'

                                    WHERE `Employee_Id` = '$Employee_Id'")
                                    or die(mysql_error());
                                 }
           else 
                {
                  $sql="INSERT INTO ad_info (
                                              Employee_Id,
                                              Job_Title,
                                              Job_Description
                                            )
                                     VALUES (
                                             '$Employee_Id',
                                             '$Job_Title',
                                             '$Job_Description'
                                            )";
                   if(!mysql_query($sql))
                   {
                                             die('cannot store in job info'.mysql_error());}




                                             }
```

Comment: Thanks it works for only updates then does not update completly

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to get the employee id from the parenttable in order to update the child table 
as you are using into update statement of child table.

Add this line of code and then execute it again:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Employee_info` WHERE `Name_Of_Employee` = '$Name'";
$sqlsearch = mysql_query($query);
$resultcount = mysql_numrows($sqlsearch);
if ($resultcount > 0) 
{
   $row=mysql_fetch_assoc ($sqlsearch);
   $Employee_Id= $row['Employee_Id']; // add this line in your code here 

   .....
```

Comment: works for only few a inserts then stops what could be the problem

Comment: it will update only for those emp which exist in the empoyee_info table